# get_multi_async using ndb tasklets

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have two ndb classes - user and images.

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    created_at = data.UTCDateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = data.UTCDateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=True, indexed=False)

    age = ndb.IntegerProperty()

    name = ndb.StringProperty()

    is_verified = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=False)
    completed_at = data.UTCDateTimeProperty(indexed=False)



class Image(ndb.Model):
    created_at = data.UTCDateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = data.UTCDateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=True, indexed=False)

    file = ndb.KeyProperty(indexed=False)
    user = ndb.KeyProperty()

    filename = ndb.StringProperty()
    image_url = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
```

There can be multiple images of a user in Image table. I have to get the top 3 images of every user. I want to fetch all records in a single call. I have to do this using ndb tasklet. i am new to ndb, so any help will be appreciated....

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little vague.  What have you tried so far?  You also haven't described how you are relating the images to the User.

I am going to assume you are creating the `Image` entities with the `User` instance as a parent in the key.

e.g.

```
 img = Image(parent=some_user.key)
```

So now we can retrieve images for the user.  Though you haven't defined what constitutes the top 3 images so I will assume it based on the most recent 3 images.

```
 images = Image.query(ancestor=some_user.key).order(Image.updated_at).fetch(3)
```

This gives us 3 Image entities.

Now we have some problems. You are storing a filename and an image URL.  Why keep the filename if you are storing the image some where else ?  Is this really the case, or are you actually planning to store the image in the datastore or in GCS, if either of these two options are the case then you need to change you image class appropriately.  If you are only storing the URL to some remote image resource, then I can't see any reason to use a tasklet, in fact not sure of any reason to use a tasklet at the moment at all.

So to move forward on a solution you need to include how you are storing/serving the images and from where.  Then we can elaborate further on the solution.